# Two-Way Hash in Bash?

Tags: bash

I call a binary [used to set the state of an external device over IP] from a bash script with arguments that are not (easily) human readable (meaningful). e.g. "video2,cbl,sat"

Consequently, I call the bash script with a more user-friendly argument, e.g. "amazon", and use an associative array to get the unfriendly argument:

```
declare -A state=( [amazon]="video2,cbl,sat" )
input_arg=${state[amazon]}
/usr/bin/set_state source:"$input_arg"
```

This is fine when I set `state`, but I also need to get `state` and return this to the [human] user, so I have the reverse hash:

```
declare -A current_state=( [video2,cbl,sat]="amazon" )
output=$(/usr/bin_get_state)
friendly_output=${current_state["$output"]}
echo "$friendly_output"
```

Is there a way to have a two-way hash in bash without maintaining two such arrays?

The same array could be used to store maps in both directions. It would work, but it doesn't feel quite right!

Comment: There's currently no way to assing the whole hash, so you need to assign it in a loop key by key.

Comment: I don't think that really addresses my question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Lorccan : bash does not offer a function to calculate an inverted hash out of an existing one, so you have to write explicit code for creating it.

Comment: are key-value guaranteed to be unique (bijective)? ie. could there be `k1>v1, k2>v1`?

Comment: @jhnc all keys and values are definitely unique

Comment: if keys and values are unique why not use a single array? a function to scan values and return an index should be relatively simple/easy to write; will the array be so large that a full scan takes 'too long'? 'course, a second copy of a 'large' array may cause issues with memory usage ...

Comment: @markp-fuso You’re right. I was considering this - as I noted at the end of my question. The array will not be large, so I might go this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't provide any means to invert a hash, so you need to iterate it yourself key by key.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A state
state=([amazon]="video2,cbl,sat"
       [netflix]="video3,cbl,inet")

declare -A current_state
for key in "${!state[@]}" ; do
    current_state["${state[$key]}"]=$key
done
```

You might need to verify the values are unique:

```
for key in "${!state[@]}" ; do
    if [[ ${current_state["${state[$key]}"]} ]] ; then  # Fix your syntax HL, SO! "
        echo Duplicate "$key". >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a useful way to maintain the reverse hash table.